# Checking Request Attribute in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to check a request attribute in a jsp to show/hide certain html.

```
request.setAttribute("submitted", "true");
```

jsp:

```
<c:if test="${submitted == 'false'}">
  // some html
</c:if>
```

But no matter what value I set in the attribute, the condition always evaluates to false.
Is the attribute not visible inside the condition?

Sahil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
request.setAttribute("submitted", true);
```

and in your JSP:

```
<c:if test="${submitted}">
    // some html
</c:if>
```

Comment: it won't work if you have an iterator tag like `<c:forEach items="${listItem@}" var ="singleItem">` This doesn't evaluate request attribute (only pageContext and session)....just a note